# RxJava Subject emits on incorrect scheduler

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, scheduler, subject

I have a following class which I hold as a singleton:

```
public class SessionStore {
    Subject<Session, Session> subject;

    public SessionStore() {
       subject = new SerializedSubject<>(BehaviorSubject.create(new Session());
    }

    public void set(Session session) {
        subject.onNext(session);
    }

    public Observable<UserSession> observe() {
        return subject.distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}
```

In activity I observe the session and perform network operation on each change:

```
private Subscription init() {
    return sessionStore
            .observe()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .flatMap(new Func1<Session, Observable<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Object> call(Session session) {
                    return retrofitService.getAThing();
                }
            })
            .subscribe(...);
}
```

When I subscribe to the session store, the subject emits on `io()` immediatelly as it is a `BehaviourSubject` and subscriber performs on `mainThread()`.

The issue comes when I call `sessionStore.set(new AnotherSession())` while already subscribed to it. IMO this should execute stream defined in `init()` on the `io()` scheduler. However what happens instead is that the stream executes on the same thread the `subject.onNext()` was called on. Resulting into `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as I am doing an network operation in `flatMap()`.

Do I understand subjects wrong? Do I misuse them this way? What is the proper solution then please?

I've also tried to replace the whole subject approach with `Observable.fromEmitter()` in `observe()` method, but suprisingly the output was the very same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

please have a look at the following part from the book '[Reactive Programming with RxJava](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920042228.do)'

*By default calling onNext() on a Subject is directly propagated to all Observer's onNext() callback methods. It is not a surprise that these methods share the same name. In a way, calling onNext() on Subject indirectly invokes onNext() on each and every Subscriber.*

Lets recap:
If you call onNext on a Subject from Thread-1, it will invoke onNext to subscriber from Thread-1. onSubscribe will be discared.

So first things first:
On which Thread will the subscription happen for:

```
retrofitService.getAThing()
```

I will just guess, and say it is the invoking thread. Which would be the thread described in observeOn, which is the Android-UI-Loop.

Every value under observeOn will be shifted from Thread-a to Thread-b as specified by the scheduler. The observeOn should on the UI-Loop should happen right before the subscription. Every value which will be received in the subscription would be on the UI-Loop, which will not block the UI thread or end in an exception.

Pease have a look at the example code and the output:

```
class SessionStore {
    private Subject<String, String> subject;

    public SessionStore() {
        subject = BehaviorSubject.create("wurst").toSerialized();
    }

    public void set(String session) {
        subject.onNext(session);
    }

    public Observable<String> observe() {
        return subject
                .asObservable()
                .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("Receiving value on Thread:: " + Thread.currentThread()))
                .distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}

@Test
public void name() throws Exception {
    // init
    SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();

    TestSubscriber testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber();
    Subscription subscribe = sessionStore
            .observe()
            .flatMap(s -> {
                return Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                    System.out.println("flatMap Thread:: " + Thread.currentThread());
                    return s;
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
            })
            .doOnNext(s -> System.out.println("After flatMap Thread:: " + Thread.currentThread()))
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // imagine AndroidScheduler here
            .subscribe(testSubscriber); // Do UI-Stuff in subscribe

    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("set on Thread:: " + Thread.currentThread());
        sessionStore.set("123");
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        System.out.println("set on Thread:: " + Thread.currentThread());
        sessionStore.set("345");
    }).start();

    boolean b = testSubscriber.awaitValueCount(3, 3_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    Assert.assertTrue(b);
}
```

Output::

```
Receiving value on Thread:: Thread[main,5,main]
flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
After flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
set on Thread:: Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
set on Thread:: Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
Receiving value on Thread:: Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
After flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
Receiving value on Thread:: Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
After flatMap Thread:: Thread[RxIoScheduler-2,5,main]
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't thought about defining the scheduler for the Observable created inside flatMap. I thought that if I define the scheduler after the flat map it will apply to the whole stream.

Comment: Well it depends on what you are trying to achieve. You could have used observeOn before the flatMap. Every value down the chain would have been moved from the point of observeOn from a thread X to another. But, you by specifing the subscribeOn onto the observable in the flatMap you achieved concurrency. So there is a difference between onSubscribe / onObserve. OnObserve may be place several times in one observable in order to move emissions to another thread. For subscribeOn there should be only one for an observable because the subscribeOn which is the most upper will be used.

Comment: Taking that into account, what I don't understand then is why the stream behave differently when I remove the `subscribeOn()` from inside of `flatMap()` and put it one step before. Like `sessionStore.observe().subscribeOn().flatMap()...`

Comment: In the flatMap you are creating a new observable, which will use subscribeOn. FlatMap subscribes for each item to the observable (with subscribeOn) and merges all emitted values values. Lets think about 3 emitted values with onNext. Each value will be used in flatMap, which will result in a new observable which will be subscribed on. You will have three streams which will be merged together, all emitting from different threads. If you use subscribeOn before flatMap, it will just say that subscription to given observable will happen on given scheduler. No concurrency happening unlike flatMap

Comment: Hey, could you try to answer this one also please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762911/call-another-retrofit-call-on-subject-emission

Answer (score 1):

When you call the  operator it affects the whole downstream. If you call:

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

in the incorrect place, the rest of the stream is executed on the specified thread.

I suggest you to always add:

```
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

at the very end of the stream:

```
private Subscription init() {
    return sessionStore
            .observe()
            .flatMap(new Func1<Session, Observable<Object>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Object> call(Session session) {
                    return retrofitService.getAThing();
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(...);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though I do specify schedulers at the end of the stream, the issue is till there.

Comment: `retrofitService.getAThing()` does not specify any schedulers?

Comment: Nope. Also I have simplified the example for better readibility.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting that your `Subject` is also an observer so in order to get the `onNext` to run on an io thread try

```
public class SessionStore {
    Subject<Session, Session> subject;

    public UserSessionStore() {
       subject = new SerializedSubject<>(BehaviorSubject.create(new Session())).observeOn(Schedulers.io());
    }

    public void set(Session session) {
        subject.onNext(session);
    }

    public Observable<UserSession> observe() {
        return subject.distinctUntilChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried that one as well. But by adding the `io()` after `distinctUntilChanged()`. Also I believe you've meant `subscribeOn()` and not `observeOn()` and that the `SerializedSubject`'s constructor takes Subject and not Observable, so you cannot do it the way you've writen.

Comment: Yes it's a typo on my part. The `observeOn` should be on the `SerializedSubject` but it should still be `observeOn`.